# calling execve() + changing PWD

Tags: c++, exec, environment-variables

I want to write a program `A` which executes another program `B`.
It is very important to execute program `B` from it's directory, cause it turns on program `BB` who sits in the same directory of `B`.

I mean:
`./B` will work

`./b/B` won't work

I thought about two ways to do so:

1. do `fork()`, change the PWD in env, and then call `execv()`
2. do `fork()`, create a temporal variable, `envp`, and call `execve()`

Lets say program `A` sits here: `/home/a`, and program `B` and `BB` sits here: `/home/a/b`

This is my code of program `A` who sits in `/home/a`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {

    int pid;
    char *cmd[20] = {"/home/a/b/B", NULL};

    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {

        /*if (putenv("PWD=/home/a/b") < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error PWD%s\n", strerror(errno));
        }*/

        char *envp[20] = {"PWD=/home/a/b", NULL};

        execve( cmd[0], cmd, envp);

        fprintf(stderr, "error: execv: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
    } else if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: fork: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
        }

    fprintf(stderr, "father quits\n");
```

return 0;
}

I tried both of my solutions, but none of them worked,
I mean, I manage to execute program `B`, but it can't find program `BB`.
I also printed program's `B`'s PWD, and it's `/home/a/b/` - but still, it cannot execute `BB`.

Is it possible?
Can someone see what I am I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`chdir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir) instead of the `envp` manipulation.